# Vlookup only display first two rows in a table

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a cell that has a list data validation type with 5 options. I am using vlookup to search a table, find that selected option and then display the results. However, when i pick option 3-5, the results do not change.

This is what I am using for the vlookup.

```
=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C13,Veggies,2)*D13, "")
```

In a second case where i have the same setup, it will only display the first row in the table as results even if i select other options.

Comment: =IFERROR(VLOOKUP(C13,Veggies,2, **FALSE**)*D13, "")`

Comment: Yeah, i tried that one too, i must have gotten the same result for two items and assumed it didn't work. It seems to be working with the FALSE added. Thanks!